# using cells in grid as buttons and drop-down list

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have created a grid wit n*n column with wxpython using wx.grid.Grid class. I want to use some of the cells of the grid as a drop-down list and some as buttons. How can widgets be implemented as a part of grid class in wxpython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wxPython demo shows how to put checkboxes in it. The event you want is probably wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_CLICK, so when you click on the cell, you could check which cell you clicked on and react appropriately. Even if you can't use a custom cell renderer, you could create a little frame with the widget you need over the cell you clicked on.